dspy-ai==2.4.5 dependency issues with instructor library
I am trying to install dspy-ai==2.4.5 which needs pydantic version 2.5.0 along with instructor library which needs minimum pydantic version 2.7.0. I am using poetry for dependency management.
Following is an issue I am facing:
Because no versions of instructor match >1.2.3,<2.0.0
 and instructor (1.2.3) depends on pydantic (2.7.0), instructor (>=1.2.3,<2.0.0) requires pydantic (2.7.0).
And because dspy-ai (2.4.5) depends on pydantic (2.5.0)
 and no versions of dspy-ai match >2.4.5,<3.0.0, instructor (>=1.2.3,<2.0.0) is incompatible with dspy-ai (>=2.4.5,<3.0.0).
So, because personal-graph depends on both dspy-ai (^2.4.5) and instructor (^1.2.3), version solving failed.



I need to install both instructor and dspy-ai ,but version solving failed.
Is their any way to solve this issue?

To tackle the problem, I experimented with different versions of dspy-ai alongside the instructor library to assess their compatibility, as there wasn't any documentation/resources available regarding their compatibility with pydantic.
After some trial and error, I managed to resolve the versioning issue by downgrading dspy-ai to version 2.3.0 while keeping the instructor library at its latest version, 1.2.2. This adjustment successfully addressed the compatibility concerns, and the application now functions smoothly.
